# Weibel "Introduction to homological algebra" Main Theorem 4.4.16

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra, proof-explanation

I can't understand the proof of Main Theorem 4.4.16  from Weibel's book "An Introduction to homological algebra".

The Theorem states

> Let $R$ be a local noetherian commutative ring, then $R$ is regular iff $\operatorname{gl.dim}(R)<\infty$.

Let $\mathfrak m$ is maximal ideal of $R$ and $k=R/\mathfrak m$.

Namely I can't understand this part:

> Now the image of $\mathfrak m/x\mathfrak m$ in $S=R/xR$ is $\mathfrak m/xR=\mathfrak mS$, so we get exact sequences $$
> 0\ \to xR/x\mathfrak m\to \mathfrak m/x\mathfrak m\to \mathfrak m S\to0\ \operatorname{and} 0\to\mathfrak mS\to S\to k\to 0.
> $$Moreover, $xR/x\mathfrak m \cong \operatorname{Tor}^R_1(R/xR,k) \cong k$, and the image of $x$ in $xR/x\mathfrak m$ is nonzero.

How did he conlcude that $xR/x\mathfrak m \cong \operatorname{Tor}^R_1(R/xR,k)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To try to give a complete answer I use and ideal $I \subseteq R$ and ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ in our case $I=xR$ and assume $I \subseteq \mathfrak{m}$, since $x \in \mathfrak{m}$ I believe. Then we claim $\operatorname{Tor}(R/I,R/\mathfrak{m})=I/I\mathfrak{m}$

consider the free resoultion
$$0\rightarrow I\rightarrow R\rightarrow R/I \rightarrow 0$$ and this gives 
$$0\rightarrow \operatorname{Tor}(R/I,R/\mathfrak{m})\rightarrow I\otimes R/\mathfrak{m}\rightarrow R\otimes R/\mathfrak{m}\rightarrow R/I \otimes R/\mathfrak{m}\rightarrow 0$$
so we must determine the kernel of the map
$I\otimes R/\mathfrak{m}\rightarrow R\otimes R/\mathfrak{m}$ which since $I\subseteq \mathfrak{m}$ the map is zero.
Thus 
$\operatorname{Tor}(R/I,R/\mathfrak{m})=I\otimes R/\mathfrak{m}=I/I\mathfrak{m}$.

However I suspect this follows from some previous result in the book.